# Reading and parsing HTML files starting from a specific line using Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this Python code I'm trying to improve in order to read and parse some HTML files, but I want it to start from the line i.e 415. Because I want to target the `<div class="panel-body">` where there's the data I want to parse. Because there's already another `<div class="panel-body">`, but it's not the right one I want to target.  Here's my code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        print('Filename: {}'.format(fname))

        with open (fname, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
            info = soup.find_all('div' ,class_= 'panel-body')
```

Comment: You can use unique surrounding elements to that `div.panel-body` element you're targeting to locate it, or some text and/or attribute of your element to easily identify it, then there is also it's index in the find_all array if it's unique you can use that as well. However you'll have to provide a snippet of the HTML containg your element so we can get some insight on the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the lines starting from 415 till end. Pass this block to `BeautifulSoup` to get data out of HTML. Here is the code.

```
from itertools import islice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
fname =  "TestFile"
folder = "TestFolder"
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
       fname = os.path.join(folder, filename)
       print('Filename: {}'.format(fname))
with open (fname, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    block = islice(f, 415, 600)
    for line in block:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'html.parser')
        info = soup.find_all('div', class_='panel-body')
```